# cursor: no-drop; при pointer-events: none;

Tags: html, css, css3, cursor

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите мне, пожалуйста, возможно ли с помощью CSS добиться такого эффекта, чтобы элемент (например,ссылка) вёл себя, как при pointer-events: none для кликов, но чтобы на нем работало свойство cursor (именно на нем, а не на других элементах)?

Хочу так:

```
.no{
  cursor: no-drop;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Но `cursor: no-drop;` не работает при `pointer-events: none;`. Без `pointer-events: none;` отлично работает.

Пример с `cursor: no-drop;` и без `pointer-events: none;` [здесь](https://jsfiddle.net/j93ycr4x/3/)

Answer (score 2):

`pointer-events: none` и `cursor` взаимоисключающие, если их применять к одному и тому же элементу. Добавьте `pointer-events` ко внутреннему элементу, а `cursor` ко внешнему:

```css
.no{
  cursor: no-drop;
  background: #1DB6BD;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
}
.no span{
  padding:10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.no2{
  cursor: no-drop;
  background: #1DB6BD;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
}
.no2 span{
  padding:10px;
  pointer-events: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a class="no"><span>Без pointer-events</span></a>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<a class="no2"><span>С pointer-events</span></a>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо Вам!:)

Comment: Проверил только сейчас. Не работает `pointer-events: none;` для ссылки. Ссылка по прежнему активна (срабатывает). Рано отметил вопрос правильным:) Видимо только тегу `<a>` надо давать `pointer-events: none;`, чтобы был запрет по клику на ссылку.